# Using AsyncTask and restarting method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

It's my first project so excuse me for rough code, especially for this if() thing;) I will try to fix it later.

**1 Problem** - When app starts it's doesn't show UI what I did in Activity Main layout.My UI shows up when result is sent to display.

I think I need to add AsyncTask somewhere. I have tryied follow some examples, but I'm doing something wrong. Maybe someone can help me what code and where I need, to see my app UI right after app launches.

**2 Problem** - How can I restart audioRecord task in program, right after first result is sent to the screen?
At the moment I'm breaking the while loop to able send the text to screen.
If I'm trying to set text from loop, during loop is running, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

**MainActivity.java code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING =       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

public AudioRecord recorder = null;
int numCrossing, p, numSamples;
short audioData[];
public int frequency;
public boolean recording;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String TAG = "tulemus";
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,     bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
    recording = true;
    audioData = new short[bufferSize];
    int[] values;
    int k = 0, t = 0;

    values = new int[2];

    while (recording) {
        numCrossing = 0;
        numSamples = 0;
        recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);
        int mod = (bufferSize / 4) * 4;

        for (p = 0; p < mod; p += 4) {
            if (audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 1] > 0 && audioData[p + 2] <= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 1] < 0 && audioData[p + 2] >= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 2] > 0 && audioData[p + 3] <= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 2] < 0 && audioData[p + 3] >= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 3] > 0 && audioData[p + 4] <= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p + 3] < 0 && audioData[p + 4] >= 0) numCrossing++;
            numSamples += 4;
        }
        for (p = 0; p < bufferSize; p++) {
            if (audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) numCrossing++;
            if (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0) numCrossing++;
            numSamples++;
        }

        frequency = (8000 / numSamples) * numCrossing;

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(frequency));

        if (frequency >= 2550 && frequency <= 2750 && (values[0] != 2)) {
            values[0] = 1;
            values[1] = 2;
            k = 1;
        }//if

        if (frequency <= 3090 && frequency >= 2900 && (values[0] == 0)) {
            values[0] = 2;
            values[1] = 1;
            k = 1;
        }//if

        if (frequency <= 3090 && frequency >= 2900 && (values[0] == 1)) {
            t = 1;
            break;
        }//if

        if (frequency >= 2550 && frequency <= 2750 && (values[0] == 2)) {
            t = 2;
            break;
        }//if

        if (k != 0) {
            k = k + 1;
        }//if

        if (k == 20) {
            values[0] = 0;
            values[1] = 0;
        }//if

    }//while

    if (t == 1) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String next = "<font color='#FF0000'>&#8679</font>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(next));
        values[0] = 0;
        values[1] = 0;
    }//if

    if (t == 2) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String next = "<font color='#FFFF00'>&#8681</font>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(next));
        values[0] = 0;
        values[1] = 0;
    }//if

}//onCreate

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {

    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:clickable="false"
android:id="@+id/RelLayout"
android:focusable="false"
android:visibility="visible"
android:background="#ff000000">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity (and your app) won't be shown until onCreate() has returned, which is why you're not seeing anything. You should definitely remove recording from that function, options are move it to an asyncTask, to a service or simply to another thread with Runnable.

AsyncTask is probably the best choice, which will also help you with your second question. Just continuously record in the task, send the results to the activity and draw them on screen.

Always remember that in android the main thread should only handle visual related tasks and all work should be moved to another thread. Android provides several options to help you achieve this (like asyncTask)

Comment: Thank you for replay. I tried to figure out this AsyncTask by myself, but it seems too complicated for me at the moment.

Comment: As i understand I can use only doInBackground for my task and using UpdateProgress get results during loop while is running in background? Can I return these two Strings "next" from AsynkTask and display them using publishProgress()and setText in onProgressUpdate()?

Comment: Ok, today I'm little bit smarter than yesterday;) It seems I need to use Service because I need to run background task for a long time (hours) and AsynkTask is not ment for that, OS can kill AsynkTask very easily.

Comment: Yes, if what you mean is to run for hours a service is more appropriate. Keep in mind that services can also be killed or paused if a user locks the phone, if you want to avoid this behavior you should use a Foreground Service (the ones you see in the notification bar)

Please upvote and/or upvote my reply if it was helpful.

Comment: I can't vote because my reputation is below 15 at the moment;(